# Why _utilities.scss overwrites styles.scss and local scss

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I defined `mt-5` class in component's .scss and the root styles.scss, but both got overwritten by _utilities.scss. Wondering why.

[image]
[image]

Angular v14, bootstrap 5.1.3

Comment: Because it has !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-top` in `_utilities.scss` has `!important` property.

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Comment: Ah, forgot this one!